# How do I factor the polynomial $x^3−5x^2+7x+13$ completely?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I factor the polynomial $x^3−5x^2+7x+13$ completely?

This polynomial seems a bit challenging. I'm not sure if I should first group it by factoring.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

$-1$ is a root of the polynomial, hence reducing the problem to a quadratic factorization problem.

Comment: A note to add to this: One can find that $-1$ is a root via the Rational Root Theorem - the only possibilities one needs to check are $\{-13,-1,1,13\}$.

Comment: A further general trick for finding roots of polynomials: if a polynomial of degree $n$ has roots $r_1, r_2, ... r_k$, for $1 \leq r \leq k$ then it can be factored into the form $(x - r_1)(x - r_2)...(x-r_k)g(x)$ (where $g(x)$ is the "unfactorable" bit; if $n=k$ then $g(x) \equiv 1$). So a simple way to easily factor polynomials, albeit somewhat "cheating," can be reduced to the matter of finding roots of it.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer I don't really see how this is cheating... I'd even encourage it in algebra students, since it reinforces the deep underlying connection between factoring and roots.

Comment: I mean cheating in the sense that, usually what you factor in class, the teacher wants a specific method usually, depending on context. If you're going it on your own or whatever, it's absolutely valid and useful, at least if you can find said roots easily (trial and error, graphing, or some other more elaborate method), but at least school usually is also testing your knowledge on the method. If that makes any sense?

Comment: If this answered your  question, please accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The given polynomial is $ x^3-5x^2+7x+13$.

By Rational root Theorem,

$ \frac{p}{q}$ will be a root if $ p$ divides the coefficient of constant term $13$ and $q$ divides the coefficient of leading term $x^3$.

i.e., $ p|13$ and $q |1$

i.e., $p=\pm 13, \ \pm 1$ and $ \ q =\pm1$

Thus,

$ \frac{p}{q}=\{\pm 1, \pm 13 \}$.

Thus the only possibility of roots are

$ \{1,-1,13,-13 \}$.

Now test each of these to satisfy the polynomial.

You see that only $ \frac{p}{q}=-1$ satisfies the polynomial and thus $-1$ is a root.

Now factor the polynomial  diving with the linear factor $(x+1)$.

Write $ \begin{align} x^3-5x^2+7x+13 &=(x+1)(x^2+bx+c) \\ &=x^3+(b+1)x^2+(b+c)x+c \end{align}$

Comparing coefficients of $x$, we get

$b+1=-5 \ \Rightarrow b=-6 \\ b+c=7 \Rightarrow c=13$

Thus,

$ x^3-5x^2+7x+13 =(x+1)(x^2-6x+13)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let$$ f(x)=x^3-5x^2+7x+13$$
 Now find a solution where $f(x)=0$ instead of using trial and error you can use the Rational Root Theorem as suggested by @Siong. 
Hint if$ -1$ is root then this means $(x+1)$ is a factor of $f(x)$, then complete algebraic long division to find the other remaining factors, by doing $\frac{f(x)}{(x+1)}$.

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to find a root, we notice that $x=-1$ gives us:
$$ -1 -5 -7+13=0$$
And thus $-1$ is a root, thus $(x-(-1))=(x+1)$ should divide the polynomial and is one of the irreducible factors. One would then proceed by long division, you will get a quadratic polynomial, these are easier to factor. You will have to determine:
$$ x^3-5x^2+7x+13= (x+1)(x^2 +bx+c )$$

Now the question is to determine $b$ and $c$.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^3−5x^2+7x+13= x^3+1-5x^2+5+7x+7$$
$$ =(x+1)(x^2-x+1)-5(x-1)(x+1)+7(x+1) $$
$$ =(x+1)\Big((x^2-x+1)-5(x-1)+7\Big) $$
$$ =(x+1)\Big(x^2-6x+13\Big) $$

Since discriminant of second factor is $36-52<0$ we can not factor it in real.